# which is the condition I should use for proper working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in developing and new to Stack Overflow too. This is my first question. I'm stuck in a problem that I am describing below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".header").click(function() {
        if ($(".header-content").is(':visible')) {  
            $(".header-content").slideUp(600);  
        }
        else {
            $(this).next(".header-content").slideDown(600); 
        }
    });
```

I uploading images of my project.

first Image is when we load the page.
Second images is when i click on second div named tracking

I want to write code for this functionality in which.
1. when I load the page all div with class header should be like same as in first image.

2. when i click on any area of any one of from thee div. the class named header-content should be display block initially it is set display:none in css.
3. when i click on other div except from open div it should closed the open div first and open the current div which was clicked.
4. and at last when i click on same div twice it should close that div.

I hope you can understand my problem now.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you add a description of the issue you are having? You have included a code snippet but not stated what it should do and what does not work, or what you have tried. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What problem are you facing? It's difficult to tell just from the snippet of code you shared. Do you have a working example you can share?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what issue you're having.

Comment: which part of that 6 lines of code has you "stuck"?

Comment: This code (as pasted here) seems to be missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted question already asked here so many times. So, use ask question only if you do not find what you're looking for.

As from I get your question, you want to toggle `.header-content` classed element on click on `.header`.
In case you can use `Toggle` function of jQuery. like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header").click(function(){  
        $(".header-content").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

You can use duration of this toggle effect using parameter. Replace "slow" accordingly.